# Nzwamba OTRAG rocket. What's that and in what language?

Tags: language-identification, african-languages

The [german OTRAG rocket company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRAG_%28rocket%29) has had conducted its launches in DR Congo (Zaire at that time) in the late seventies. Several sources refer to those rockets under the name of ["Nzwamba"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5pJpd9Vi_U).

What language exactly is that? It looks like Swahili to me, but I can't find it anywhere? Google translate suggests the translation to be "Nzwamba".

What does that mean in that language?

Answer (score 1):

I am not persuaded that the project had that name in the day – I see the links, but there's no hard evidence that that name was originally associated with the rockets. It is possible that it derives from the personal name Nzwamba Simanga, who has promoted that video across the internet. The problem is that without hard historical evidence as to *how* the name was assigned, it could be any number of languages (presumably Congolese). If OTRAG assigned the name, it might have been e.g. the name of a local engineer, or a sugestion by a local engineer -- it's unlikely that the Germans would have researched an obscure word in e.g. Kinande with some special meaning like "bird" (anyhow, it doesn't mean "bird" though it could be the name of a kind of bird). There are way too many possibilities, given the number of languages spoken in Congo, and you can't find dictionaries for many of them. So in my opinion, without evidence about how the name was assigned, this can't be answered.